# Basic equation solving $t/(1+t)=1-1/(1+t)$

Tags: rational-functions

In found this equality in my math book, could anyone explain to me why it is equal?

$t/(1+t)=1-1/(1+t)$

Comment: Write $t=(1+t)-1$

Comment: $1-\frac 1 {(1+t)} = \frac  {1+t -1} {(1+t)}$.

Comment: 2/3= 1- 1/3,   3/4= 1- 1/4, 4/5= 1- 1/5, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{t}{1+t} &= 1 - \frac{1}{1+t}\\\\
              &= \frac{1+t}{1+t} - \frac{1}{1+t}\\\\
              &= \frac{1+t-1}{1+t}\\\\
              &= \frac{t}{1+t}
\end{align}

Moral of the story is; make a nice choice for the number $1$ and things often look like they should.

Answer (score 0):

To prove this, let us add 1/(1+t) to both sides.

We get:

(t+1)/(1+t) = 1

Now obviously, t+1 = 1+t, so the left side of the equations is equal to one.

Comment: Not sure this is the best approach as it assumes the relationship true to begin with.  I see what you have tried to illustrate though.

Comment: Didn't the other answer also do the same thing?

Comment: No. It showed both sides were equal to the same thing.

Comment: It started out with an equation in the beginning, though.

Comment: It manipulates the RHS only and shows it equal to the left. The first line is a statement of the problem and could be omitted.